# azure search find partial words mach

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I use azure search to index a table of people and professions (professional skills). My issue is that sometimes people use full name for the skill, like anjularjs or reactjs but on search they are searching for angular or react. In those cases the search won't return any mach.

How should I treat this cases? (the js suffix is only a small example, a lot more appear on real data table.)

p.s. I can't use suggest service.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best would be for you to define some synonyms (i.e. "anagularjs == angular"). We recently released this capability in preview mode:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-synonyms shows you how to use it.

If it is not possible for you to create a synonyms dictionary (maybe you can't predict which terms the user is likely to use), then you could define the match to not be exact, but tell the system how many characters to match. You can do this by creating a `[custom analyzer]` that produces tokens that are let's say at least 5 characters in length in the index so that a term like "react" end up in the index. (see edgeNGram token filtering)

To learn more about query processing and custom analyzers in Azure Search, please read: [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture).